# Не могу обратиться к атрибуту модели User в контроллере (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, атрибуты, модель

[image: Код обработчика внизу]

Задал переменную user как $user = Auth::user()
Пользователь авторизован, если прописать dd($user->nickname) то он мне выведет значение nickname, однако обратится к этой переменной чтобы перезаписать ее, у меня не выходит.

```
`public function edit(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $userData = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($userData,[
            'email' => [
            'email:rfc,dns',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
        ],
            'nickname' => ['max:20',
                Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'about' => 'nullable|max:200',
            'password' => 'nullable|min:6',
            'user_picture' => 'mimes:jpeg,png'

        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect(route('edit-page'))
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
        dd($user->nickname);
        $user->nickname = $userData['nickname'];
        $user->email = $userData['email'];
        $user->about = $userData['about'];

        if (isset($userData['password'])) {
            $user->password = $userData['password'];
        }

        if (isset($userData['user_picture']))
        $user->picture = $userData['user_picture'];

        $user->save();

        return redirect(route('main-page'));
    }`
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке в массиве $userData нет никакого никнейма. Смотрите что туда приходит, тут дело не в том, что Вы думаете

Comment: Действительно. Простите мне мой позор. Видимо, засиделся и просто не заметил ошибку в форме